# Charging Behaviour Changed After Using Car Charger

Tags: charging, nexus-5, battery-life

On a recent road trip, I used a car charger to re-charge the battery on my Nexus 5 phone. Ever since, I have noticed a significant increase in the time required to charge the battery, even when using my normal charging cable. Whereas before I could completely recharge the battery in 2-3 hours, now it is taking more like 6-8 hours. My first thought was that the car charger damaged the battery in some way, but that does not seem to be the case. I have not seen any change in the battery life, just this annoying increase in charge time.

What I'm wondering now is, could the phone be 'stuck' in the slower charging mode used when charging from usb (like a car charger)? If so is there a setting somewhere I can change to get it back to normal? Is there another possible explanation for the sudden change in charge time?

Comment: Try changing charger and cable- improbable but your charger may not be delivering required current